# SQL detect elements in OR clause

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

i need an sql which whould do somethig as follows:

```
SELECT col1, col2, cond4 as cond4_is_exclusive
FROM table
WHERE (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) OR cond4
```

Where cond4 = (col3 IN (...))

I NEED cond4_is_exclusive to be TRUE only if condition is met by cond4 itself and not by cond1 and cond2 and cond3 since there is an OR between them.

Is there a such solution?

I need an elegant and optim solution since the query is much larger and there are more conditions  and more complicated.

my current work is like:

```
SELECT col1, col2, (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) as c1, cond4 c2
    FROM table
    WHERE (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) OR cond4
```

And later c2 and c2 are checked with php which is not so elegant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work on Postgres (not sure about MySQL though - I hardly ever use it)

```
select *
from (
  SELECT col1, col2, 
         (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) as c1, 
         cond4 c2
  FROM table
) t
WHERE c1 OR c2
```

Comment: Yep, or for more complex cases use a CTE (but of course that won't work on MySQL).

Comment: This seems best. Minor gripe: never omit `AS` for *column* aliases. [Quote:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#AEN80901) `But this is impractical for output column names, because of syntactic ambiguities.`

Answer (score 2):

A solution that works in both databases is:

```
SELECT col1, col2, cond4 as cond4_is_exclusive
FROM table
WHERE (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) and (not cond4) OR
      (not (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) and cond4);
```

You could also express this with a `case` so you only have to repeat the first conditions once:

```
WHERE 1 = (case when (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3)
                then (case when cond4 then 1 else 0 end)
                when cond4 then 1
                else 0
           end)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you name it in your question: you want something *Exclusive* with *Or*. There is something called ... [Exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), namely as an operator: `XOR`.

`A xor B` means: either `A` is true, or `B` is true, but never both.

```
SELECT col1, col2, cond4 as cond4_is_exclusive
FROM table
WHERE (cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3) XOR cond4
```

Comment: Well ... [MySQL XOR Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor). Shame on Postgres that is does not have one (only for bitwise), but you can [create a funktion](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3E860952.3F1058C6@nsd.ca) for it.

Comment: If you are talking about *bitwise* XOR, then Postgres does support that (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html). But this is a boolean XOR which just happens to work in MySQL because MySQL treats numbers and "boolean" expressions the same way and thus just XORs `0` and `1` which in this case does indeed what you want.